# How to add a custom undertow HttpHandler to thorntail (fka. wildfly swarm)

Tags: java, microservices, undertow, wildfly-swarm

I started using thorntail V4 (www.thorntail.io) (formerly known as wildfly swarm) to create microservices. Yes i know the website states it as "proof of concept". Thorntail ships with undertow (www.undertow.io).

Does anyone know, how to add or register a custom undertow HttpHandler?

How do i get the next HttpHandler in the chain for calling it in handleRequest()?

My current HttpHandler looks like this:

```
import io.undertow.server.HttpHandler;
import io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustomHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Inject
    private HttpHandler next; // how do i get the next HttpHandler?

    public MyCustomHttpHandler() {
      System.out.println("MyCustomHttpHandler.java constructed"); // never gets called. How do i register it in Thorntail?
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
      // never gets called :/
      System.out.println(String.format("HttpHandler next=%s", next));

      // How do i get next? Is @Inject the way to go?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Btw. can someone add a "thorntail" tag? My StackOverflow-Rep doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler should look like:

```
public class MyCustomHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private HttpHandler next;

    public MyCustomHttpHandler(HttpHandler next) {
      this.next = next;
      System.out.println("MyCustomHttpHandler.java constructed"); // never gets called. How do i register it in Thorntail?
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
      // never gets called :/
      System.out.println(String.format("HttpHandler next=%s", next));

      // How do i get next? Is @Inject the way to go?
    }
}
```

However, at the moment it looks like Thorntail v4 doesn't support the arbitrary addition of HttpHandlers into the chain. Could you please raise an issue here: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/issues